# How to test an alert displaying using Jest + Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I need to verify that after a button click an alert is displayed.

I tried the following:

```
  it('should display an alert when the user tries to add empty value', () => {
    jest.setTimeout(100000);
    page.alert = jest.fn(text => text);
    const addButtonSelector = '#root > div > div > div.ToDoInput > button';
    expect(page).toClick(addButtonSelector);
    expect(page.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Please enter a todo!');
  })
```

But the test Fails with zero calls to the page.alert (in reality the alert is shown after the click on this button in this conditions).
Also I tried window.alert - it is not recognized.
Please help.

Update: I tried like that, and the alert function is not replaced with the mock function (???)

```
it('should display an alert when the user tries to add empty value', async() => {
    jest.setTimeout(50000);
    const dialogHandler = jest.fn();
    page.on('dialog', dialogHandler);
    const addButtonSelector = '#root > div > div > div.ToDoInput > button';
    await expect(page).toClick(addButtonSelector);
    await expect(dialogHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    const [firstCall] = dialogHandler.mock.calls;
    const [dialog] = firstCall;
    expect(dialog.message()).toEqual('Please enter a todo!');
  })
```

Comment: follow the link : https://www.w3resource.com/jest/timer-mocks.php

Comment: @LDS Hmm, I read, but I didn't get your idea. Please explain in more details as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Pupeteer's Dialog](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-class-dialog). You can set event handler once a Dialog is displayed and if you pass [jest.fn()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html) you can have reference to the dialog that it has been called with

e.g.:

```
describe('page with dialog', () => {
  const dialogHandler = jest.fn(dialog => dialog.dismiss());
  beforeAll(() => {
    page.on('dialog', dialogHandler);
  });

  describe('when the ToDoInput button is clicked', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
      await page.click('#root > div > div > div.ToDoInput > button');
    });

    it('should display a dialog', () => {
      expect(dialogHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should have message "Please enter a todo!"', () => {
      const [firstCall] = dialogHandler.mock.calls;
      const [dialog] = firstCall;
      expect(dialog.message()).toEqual('Please enter a todo!');
    });
  });
});
```

---

**Edit:** after testing it the only thing that was not working is that the test script was becoming idle until the dialog is either accepted or dismissed and after changing the `dialogHandler` to dismiss the dialog made it work flawlessly:

```
const dialogHandler = jest.fn(dialog => dialog.dismiss());
```

[here is a working example](https://github.com/Teneff/jest-pupeteer)

Comment: Please take a look on update in the question - I tried your method and it does not work for me.